# Ping Identity - How to get claims for my ASP.Net Project

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, openid-connect

I setup a Ping One application but I couldn't get the user claims details even after adding openId in resources. Im new to openId in general and not exactly sure what to do:

I have the following configurations below:

[image: configuration tab]

Under the resources tab:

[image]

On my C# code, I want to get the user emails details using something like this.

```
var userNameTag = "custom_tag";
((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == userNameTag)?.Value;
```

where custom_tag could be:
(I use this for Okta)http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
or name

For my startup
[image]

Comment: What's your Startup.cs configuration look like?

Comment: @GHDevOps I updated the question and added my startup!